# Radio button checked change style and appear text

Tags: navbar

I have to create a navigation menu using HTML and CSS without Javascript for my eBay store. What I want to do is to create many radio buttons with many labels and clicking on a label make label bold and make appear a text.

First effect on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fb2yn5ts/

(click on label make a text appears)

```
<a href="#descrizione">My Label</a>

<div id="descrizione">
This is some text
</div>
```

css

```
#descrizione{
  display: none;
}

#descrizione:target{
  display: block;
}
```

Second effect on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cv83q9ow/

(Click on label make label bold)

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="check" class="check-with-label" />
  <label for="check" class="label-for-check">My Label</label>
<div>
```

css:

```
.check-with-label:checked + .label-for-check {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I can't merge these effects into one, do you know why and how can I solve this?
Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

OK guys I solved this problem by doing this:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="navbar_menu_store" id="input_description" class="radio_item_menu">
<label for="input_description" class="label_item_menu">Description</label>
<input type="radio" name="navbar_menu_store" id="input_shipping" class="radio_item_menu">
<label for="input_shipping" class="label_item_menu">Shipping</label>

<div id="contentDescription"><p class="testo_scheda">
This is some text</p>
</div>

<div id="contentShipping"><p class="testo_scheda">
This is some other text</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#input_description:checked ~ #contentDescription, #input_shipping:checked ~ #contentShipping  {
    display: block;
}

#contentDescription, #contentShipping{
  display: none;
}

.radio_item_menu:checked + .label_item_menu {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/LLornfn8/

Thank you very much anyway!